# How to add a journal reference to a django template

Tags: django, django-templates, bibtex, doi

I want to add scientific journal references from a list to a django template.
For example, I could have the references in bibtex format in a file (it could be another format, I can adapt to what is available). I wonder if it is possible to add a particular reference from that file into a django template, for example using a key. The rendered reference would then look similar to this:

Kendrew, J. C.; Bodo, G.; Dintzis, H. M.; Parrish, R. G.; Wyckoff, H.; Phillips, D. C. A Three-Dimensional Model of the Myoglobin Molecule Obtained by X-Ray Analysis. Nature 1958, 181 (4610), 662


Are there any extensions available that do this?

Comment: You need to be more specific, exactly *what* is the data, what is the expected output?

Comment: I edited my question. I hope it is clearer now.